# Adding time to a date php

Tags: php, date, addition

here is my current issue:
I need to add a predefined amount to a selected date. I have been using this until now:

```
$date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+7 days'));
```

but this returns the current date +7 days.

How can I define the current date and the modify that using this?
lets say that I have the date defined as:

```
$udate='2014-05-06';
```

I need to add 2 months to this date.

Comment: see my answer and check

Comment: Of course a quick **look at the manual** would probably have got you an answer [strtotime() manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: I did wasted half a day for this, before posting the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do,

```
date('Y-m-d',strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($your_date)) . " +2 months"));
```

You can also do using *[DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)* object,

```
$date = new DateTime($your_date);
$interval = new DateInterval('P2M');    
$date->add($interval);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d')
```

Comment: +1 for using `DateTime` class

Comment: Or use `->modify('+2 month')` on `DateTime` object, which also works on php>=5.2.0. It is also more "readable" code :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
$date = "2014-08-25";
$newdate = strtotime ( '+2 months' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
$newdate = date ( 'Y-m-d' , $newdate );
```